# Thymeleaf: Concatenation - Could not parse as expression

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I'm having an issue when trying to concat multiple values in my template.
According to Thymeleaf [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/Tutorial%20-%20Using%20Thymeleaf%2020130224.pdf) I should simply be able to + them together...

> **4.6 CONCATENATING TEXTS**
>
> Texts, no matter whether they are literals or the result of evaluating variable or message
>   expressions, can be easily concatenated using the + operator:

```
th:text="'The name of the user is ' + ${user.name}"
```

Here is an example of what I found works:

```
<p th:text="${bean.field} + '!'">Static content</p>
```

This however doesn't:

```
<p th:text="${bean.field} + '!' + ${bean.field}">Static content</p>
```

Logically, this should work but its not, what am I doing wrong?

---

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

Here is how I've set my TemplateEngine and TemplateResolver up:

```
<!-- Spring config -->
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="fileTemplateResolver"/>
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="templateResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
```

ThymeleafTemplatingService:

```
@Autowired private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
.....
String responseText = this.templateEngine.process(templateBean.getTemplateName(), templateBean.getContext());
```

AbstractTemplate.java:

```
public abstract class AbstractTemplate {
  private final String templateName;
  public AbstractTemplate(String templateName){
    this.templateName=templateName;
  }
  public String getTemplateName() {
    return templateName;
  }
  protected abstract HashMap<String, ?> getVariables();
  public Context getContext(){
    Context context = new Context();
    for(Entry<String, ?> entry : getVariables().entrySet()){
      context.setVariable(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return context;
  }
}
```

Comment: i have the same error occured!!!!!!!!!! but i use thymeleaf and scala

Comment: The only way I've managed to make it work is to use pre-processing.
`<p th:text="${'__${bean.property1}__' + '::' + '__${bean.property2}__'}">default text</p>`

Comment: This example works for me. What version of thymeleaf are you using? Are you using any additional dialects?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

But from what I see you have quite a simple error in syntax

```
<p th:text="${bean.field} + '!' + ${bean.field}">Static content</p>
```

the correct syntax would look like

```
<p th:text="${bean.field + '!' + bean.field}">Static content</p>
```

As a matter of fact, the syntax `th:text="'static part' + ${bean.field}"` is equal to `th:text="${'static part' + bean.field}"`.

Try it out. Even though this is probably kind of useless now after 6 months.

Comment: Useless after 6 months?, It still is useful 6 years later

Comment: Still useful after 8 years

Comment: So the "concatenate outside" syntax stops working if multiple attributes are involved... Interesting. I assume localized properties have a similar thing going on?

Answer (score 42):

You can concat many kind of expression by sorrounding your simple/complex expression between `||` characters:

```
<p th:text="|${bean.field} ! ${bean.field}|">Static content</p>
```

Comment: I'm using Thymeleaf version: 2.1.1.RELEASE (it should be the last version)

Comment: Works great on version `2.1.5`

Comment: What if text contains |? For example. `"|${fullName} Stories \| Twiza|"` I'm getting Could not parse as expression.

Comment: how to do it here it did not work can you convert it to you syntax...           `th:class="'hotel listing col organic urgencyMsg available organic h-' + ${record.hotelInfo.hotelId} + '-organic'">`  am using `3.0.2`

Comment: For using vertical bar ( | ) in text : `<p>[[${fullName}]] Stories | Twiza </p>`

Answer (score 9):

Note that with | char, you can get a warning with your IDE,
for exemple I get warning with the last version of IntelliJ,
So the best solution it's to use this syntax:

```
th:text="${'static_content - ' + you_variable}"
```

Answer (score 6):

---

***We can concat Like this :***

---

```
<h5 th:text ="${currentItem.first_name}+ ' ' + ${currentItem.last_name}"></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

by the way, if you need to concatenate a value from the property file with something else in Thymeleaf attribute, surprisingly enough, the following works:

```html
<input ...
th:attr="oninvalid=|setCustomValidity('#{main.my-main-error-message}')|" />
```

The above will end up rendered as:

```html
<input ... oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Some error message here')" />
```